# Swift: Storyboard TabViewController Segue Not Being Triggered

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, barcode-scanner, rsbarcodes

I am working on an iOS app that allows users to scan barcodes of food items into a shopping list. My goal is that when the scanner picks up on a barcode, it grabs the metadata and sends it (via segue) to another view where the user can log the item into their grocery list. My bug is that when the scanner picks up on barcode and successfully returns the metadata, it calls `performSegueWithIdentifier()` (line 30) but does not actually segue into the next view. It will just continually scan the barcode and output my print statements as shown below. The parent view is a TabBarViewController with three tabs, one of which being the scanner. I am using the `RSBarcodes` framework that could be found [here](https://github.com/yeahdongcn/RSBarcodes). Below are screenshots to illustrate my bug.

## Barcode Scanner Class

[image: Barcode Scanner Class]

## Terminal Output

[image]

## Storyboard Segue

[image]

## Simulator View

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stop the scanning before presenting the other viewcontroller. Find the implemented method to stop or deallocate the scanner in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Sachin Rocken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4615157) said, you need to stop the the capture session to avoid multiple scans. Simply using `self.session.stopRunning()` will seize the capture session. Also, any UI operation done within `ScanItemViewController` needs to be done on the main thread. Your `self.barcodesHandler` should model:

```
self.barcodesHandler = { barcodes in
    // print barcode found
    self.barcodeVal = barcodes[0].stringValue
    self.session.stopRunning() // Stops scanning processs to avoid multiple scans
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("presentAddItem", sender: self)
     }) // Any UI operation needs to be done on main thread            
}
```